# How to use number intervals in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a group of folders:

```
$ ls -d _clip* 
_clip10.trim  _clip12.trim  _clip14.trim  _clip16.trim  _clip2.trim  _clip4.trim  _clip6.trim  _clip8.trim
_clip11.trim  _clip13.trim  _clip15.trim  _clip1.trim   _clip3.trim  _clip5.trim  _clip7.trim  _clip9.trim
```

I need to select tow batch of folders, one from `_clip1.trim` to `_clip6.trim`:

```
$ ls -d _clip[1-6].trim 
_clip1.trim  _clip2.trim  _clip3.trim  _clip4.trim  _clip5.trim  _clip6.trim
```

And other from `_clip7.trim` to `_clip16.trim`, but when I try with `ls -d _clip[7-16].trim` only list the `_clip6.trim` is listed.

I need to understand how to use the number interbals in regulars expressions. Thanks for your time!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: Note that globs (aka wildcards) in the shell are *not* regular expressions. They have some features in common, but they also conflict with each other in fundamental ways (e.g. '*' means different things for shell globs than it does for regex).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[...]` is a character class. When you say `[7-16]`, that means "the characters from 7 to 1 (none), and the character 6." I would say use two expressions: `_clip[7-9].trim _clip1[0-6].trim`. It looks like you don't have all of them in that range, but if you did you could use `_clip{7..16}.trim`.

Also, on the command line, they're globs, not regexes. There are a few differences - `*` means anything or nothing, not 0+ of whatever's in front of it, same with `?` (zero or one of anything, not the previous expression).

Answer (score 0):

how about using the argument generator

```
$ echo _clip{1..6}.trim
_clip1.trim _clip2.trim _clip3.trim _clip4.trim _clip5.trim _clip6.trim
$ echo _clip{7..16}.trim
_clip7.trim _clip8.trim _clip9.trim _clip10.trim _clip11.trim _clip12.trim _clip13.trim _clip14.trim _clip15.trim _clip16.trim
```

these are not regexpes...bash can generate arguments:

```
$ echo x{0..1}_{FOO,BAR}_{x,y}
x0_FOO_x x0_FOO_y x0_BAR_x x0_BAR_y x1_FOO_x x1_FOO_y x1_BAR_x x1_BAR_y
```